# How to let python type checker know that it should return a new instance of its class?

Tags: python, annotations, subclass, typechecking

I wanna use classmethod to return a new instance of current class, and I have try some code like below, but it raise a NameError('name 'T' is not defined')

Put the code `T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)` on `class A` above does not work neither.

Is there any good idea to handle it?

```
import json
from typing import TypeVar


class A(dict):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(dict, self).__init__()
        self["name"] = name


    @classmethod
    def foo(cls: T, args: str)->T:
        return json.loads(args)
T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)


class B(A):
    pass

b = B(name='B')
# True
print(isinstance(b.foo(json.dumps(b)),B))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string to make a forward reference to `A` and give `cls` the correct type of `Type[T]`:

```
import json
from typing import Type, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T', bound='A')


class A(dict):
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(name=name)

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls: Type[T], args: str) -> T:
        return cls(**json.loads(args))


class B(A):
    def is_b(self) -> bool:
        return True


b = B.foo('{"name": "foo"}')
print(b.is_b())
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works, but I could't see any hint on pycharm. It looks like a bug of this IDE because pycharm does not fully implement the pep484 standard[pycharm 2017.1.3].